# Regular expression to get text between 2 string

Tags: php, regex

Hi i need to get the content between 2 strings similar to tags like this:

```
[code]
some text and 
new line 
[/code]
```

I try with this regular expression but it works only without new line :

```
preg_match("/\[view\](.*)\[\/view\]/",$string, $results);
```

I need something that works also with newlines! and any characters i put between these 2 "tags" 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `s` modifier in your call to do a multiline search:

```
preg_match("/\[view\](.*)\[\/view\]/s",$string, $results);
```

In the end, you should not be using regex to do complex parsing.  It isn't up to the job.  Find a markup language that suits your purpose and use an existing library to parse it.

Comment: Thank you! it works also with a "s" modifier (just discovered:P) Thank you

Comment: @Asap In fact it does not work with an `m` modifier; the correct answer is, as you say, the `s` modifier. Sorry for my previous incorrect answer...

Comment: Try running it against `[view]foo[view]bar[/view]baz[/view]`, what will you get?

Comment: @ircmaxwell It's a good point, and I've added a note about using a real parser.